# How to remove HTML tags in JavaScript, but holding the character "<" when ther's not the character ">"

Tags: javascript, html, html-parsing

There's a way to parse the HTML in Javascript holding the character `<` when the tag's not closed without replacing HTML chars?

Talking about a string like `<html>efrferrefrer<wedw`.

It have to gives back `efrferrefrer<wedw`.

Trying with

```
    function removeHtmlTags(input){
        let tmp = document.createElement("div");
        tmp.innerHTML = input;
        return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
    }
    //or
    function removeHtmlTags(input){
        return input.replace(/<[^>]*>?/gm, '');
    }
```

does not gives the desired result.

It eliminates "<wedw".

So, there's a way that do this **without using functions that replacing html characters** like

```
    function escapeHtml(text) {
        var map = {
            '&': '&amp;',
            '<': '&lt;',
            '>': '&gt;',
            '"': '&quot;',
            "'": '&#039;'
        };
        return = text.replace(/[&<>"']/g, function(m) { return map[m]; });
    }
```

It have to be exactly `efrferrefrer<wedw`.

Comment: What you're looking for will require that you write a customized DOM parser, because the string you've shown, when parsed according to standard HTML parsing rules (which are **mega** complex), does not consider that unterminated tag to be text. So `DOMParser` and such won't work. Please note that you **cannot** reliably parse HTML using a simple regex. It's much too complicated for that, and any attempt that you think "Yeah, that's good enough for what I'm doing" **will** fail in the wild. This is a lesson many, many have learned over time. You've been warned. :-)

Comment: The issue with the RegExp approach is introduced [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1169519), the issue with the HTML parser (`textContent`) is, that `<` is always interpreted to begin a start tag in HTML when you set `innerHTML`. That is, you should parse only valid HTML, i.e. use HTML entity instead of `<`.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder *What you're looking for will require that you write a customized DOM parser* Today you wrote a mad thing! But other things you wrote are excellently correct. *you cannot reliably parse HTML using a simple regex* > Nothing to object

Comment: Teemu - *The issue with the HTML parser (textContent) is, that < is always interpreted to begin a start tag in HTML when you set innerHTML. That is, you should parse only valid HTML, i.e. use HTML entity instead of <.* Easy to write the concept, complicated to do pratically

Comment: That's true, in practice you do the "_mad thing_". Most of the time these things are not needed at all. What is your use-case, why to even bother to remove tags from a random string?

Comment: Teemu - *That's true, in practice you do the "mad thing". Most of the time these things are not needed at all. What is your use-case, why to even bother to remove tags from a random string?* > **User's input. Must be visualized everything except HTML. There's other random user input content that should be visualized correctly, but it has not to interfere with the site css layout. So if the user writes `<big>` is better if the preview of the content makes the site unexplosive.**

Comment: Simply set `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`. If user includes tags, they see those as text, it's user's view, if they want to see tags, just let'em see tags.

Comment: Teemu - "*Simply set textContent instead of innerHTML. If user includes tags, they see those as text, it's user's view, if they want to see tags, just let'em see tags.*" **No. Should not be like you wrote. The content it's displayed also from other users and it have to be standardized. HTML tags are not allowed. Is have to be only textual, but with some data added in the middle that could contains the characters `[<>]`. Imagine a colorful stackoverflow. I would be more beautiful, but what a delirium**

Comment: To shed some ligth on what you're working with, jQuery uses RegExps as a part of its "parser", but even [jQuery can't handle](https://jsfiddle.net/70wm36fb/1/) that invalid string (either a browser can, that string inside the markup breaks the wrapping element). It's also not very useful to try to implement your own parser with JS, as you've to sanitize the input on your server anyway, any data send from a client can be spoofed, no matter how much you're sanitizing it in the browser. That's why I said that "_these things are not needed_".

Comment: @Teemu "*these things are not needed [...] no matter how much you're sanitizing it in the browser.*" - Not agree with this. Server side have to be sanitized anyway, but client side via browser a site have to be clean and "lightshining". So, good fiddle, but also if jQuery and the browsers uses RegExps its regex it's so complex that creator and other 2 or 3 genius in the world known what procedures it has. Server side it's simpler there are so much functions to strip tags... Are JQuery and JavaScript the problems, also because their regex are "differents"

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly but if the target is just replacing `<xxxx>` and `</xxxx>` tags then try this

```js
    const p = '<html>efrferrefrer<wedw';
     // const regex = /<\/{0,1}[A-Z]+>{1}/igm;
    const regex = /<\/{0,1}[0-9:%;A-Z\s="]+>{1}/igm;
    console.log(p.replace(regex, ''));

    const p2 = '<html>efrferrefrer<wedw</html><html>';
    console.log(p2.replace(regex, ''));

    const p3 = `<head>test header
</head>
<body>
    <h4>Tag remover</h4></unclose
    <div>
            <label for="a">HTML</label><br>
            <textarea id="a" name="a" rows="5" style="width:100%;"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="output"></div> 
    <div id="output2"></div>`;
console.log(p3.replace(regex, ''));
```

Comment: You can't use a simple regex to parse HTML reliably. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454 *(edit: not my downvote)*

Comment: i dont think he is talking about parsing but rather replacing <XXXX> and </XXXX> strings with empty strings. maybe i understood it wrong

Comment: They're talking about parsing, if they want that `<html>` part to be considered a tag. (And then there's the [tag:html-parsing] tag on the question.)

Comment: @Apostolos "*i dont think he is talking about parsing but rather replacing <XXXX> and </XXXX> strings with empty strings. maybe i understood it wrong*" YESSSSSSSSSS

Comment: @xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa i updated my answer and made it a little smarter and used your example (Without the `<script>` tag) to show the results. regards. please dont quote the comments :)

Comment: @Apostolos - Seen. Good example (I update too mine). I quote the comments because you have to know what I'm referring for. The `script` tag was here to display the results in the output `div`. Anyway regex it's not "parsing" HTML and it not replies correctly to this answer. So thanks. You can update it as you want, but for this it's needed an hyper smart boy . A small step for man a big step for humanity. Hoping this helps